Flutter GetX Contextless Navigation Error: in xCode | Android Studio Emulator App Works fine
It's been a week, since I am stuck at this error. I am completely new to Flutter Development, have basic knowledge of Android Native development.
Importantly, this was working fine, I am not sure what changed in the last few days, that it started giving me this error.
I am open to share any information, or screenshots, that may help you identify the issue, as this is the app in development.
The screenshot of the error on the iOS Simulator is: 
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: You are trying to use contextless navigation without
      a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
      If you are testing your app, you can use:
      [Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
      a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
      for a [GetMaterialApp].
      
#0      GetNavigation.global (package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:1094:7)
#1      GetNavigation.offAll (package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:970:12)
#2      AuthenticationRepository.initializeAuth (package:bttdriver/data/repositories/authentication/authentication_repository.dart:77:11)
<asynchronous suspension>

The message says that I need to use GetMaterialApp, which I already use. Code for app.dart
// lib/app.dart
import 'package:bttdriver/utils/logging/logger.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'bindings/general_bindings.dart';
import 'data/apicalls/network_helper.dart';
import 'routes/app_routes.dart';
import 'utils/constants/colors.dart';
import 'utils/constants/text_strings.dart';
import 'utils/theme/theme.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final NetworkHelper networkHelper;

  const App({super.key, required this.networkHelper, required String flavor});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TLoggerHelper.debug("Flavor: ${appFlavor!}" );
    return GetMaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // Set the navigator key here
      title: TTexts.appName,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: TAppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: TAppTheme.darkTheme,
      // debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: ! ("prod" == appFlavor),
      initialBinding: GeneralBindings(),
      getPages: AppRoutes.pages,
      /// Show Loader or Circular Progress Indicator meanwhile Authentication Repository is deciding to show relevant screen.
      home: const Scaffold(backgroundColor: TColors.primary, body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white))),
    );
  }
}

The code for main_dev.dart is as follows, which calls the mainCommon function.  And, it goes the same for main_staging.dart and maing_prod.dart, with the changed flavor name.
import 'main_common.dart';
import 'firebase_options/firebase_options_dev.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  const apiBaseUrl = "https://dev.bttransport.com.au/api";

  await mainCommon("dev", apiBaseUrl, DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
}


And, the main_common.dart is as follows:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

import 'app.dart';
import 'data/apicalls/network_helper.dart';
import 'data/repositories/authentication/authentication_repository.dart';
import 'services/location_service.dart';

/// Entry point of Flutter App
Future<void> mainCommon(String flavor, String apiBaseUrl, FirebaseOptions currentPlatform) async {
  final WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await GetStorage.init();

  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);

  final networkHelper = NetworkHelper(apiBaseUrl);
  Get.put(networkHelper); // Store NetworkHelper in GetX for global access

  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(name: flavor, options: currentPlatform);
    Get.put(AuthenticationRepository());
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle Firebase initialization error
    print('Error initializing Firebase: $e');
  }

  // Initialize LocationService if needed
  LocationService();

  runApp(App(networkHelper: networkHelper, flavor: flavor));
}

I have tried many things, including cleaning and rebuilding the app completely. Even cleaning the pods.
For some reason, this is working perfectly in Android Emulator.
